# Time signatures and music

Tags: time-signatures

My daughter has created a piece of music for her B-Tec music production class in which the time signature changes, but the tutor is trying to argue that this is not correct. Can someone please clarify for me, whether it is acceptable for a piece of music to change time signatures? I'm getting the impression it is okay - but why is this musically acceptable?

Comment: It's acceptable, but your daughter's tutor could nonetheless be right.

Comment: There are no *absolute* standards of "correct" or "acceptable". Without clarification on what the tutor *meant*, this is unanswerable.

Comment: Without knowing the criteria for the course, it's an impossible question to answer with regard to that. Obviously it's acceptable, as it happens a fair bit, reason being, the music, in the writer's (and player's) view, needs that to happen.

Comment: Is the tutor saying "categorically wrong", "wrong in this assignment", "not accurately reflecting the composition", or something else?  Also: Please edit the question to clarify "B-tec".  (Which is apparently [BTEC](https://qualifications.pearson.com/en/qualifications/btec-technicals/music-production.html) and a region-specific program, but not [this Btec](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Btec) or [this btec](https://www.btecsolutions.com/).)

Comment: Voting to close, needing more details. One option that I haven’t noticed being discussed yet is that the meter change was acceptable but incorrectly executed; e.g. maybe the new time signature didn’t match the actual number of beats in each bar. Please tell more about the teacher’s objection and if possible post the music.

Answer (score 4):

Well, like so many other aspects of music, the answer is *it depends*. In this case, the most important considerations are (1) what are the specific requirements for the music production class and (2) what genre of music is she creating.

**Requirements**

If the syllabus explicitly dictates that the time signature must not change, then that is that.  There may be a reason for this.  The instructor may be working with musical novices who need practice fitting rhythms within a time signature properly.  Allowing students to simply change the time signature when their music doesn't fit would subvert this.  Or maybe the software in use doesn't work well with changing time signatures and so this is a requirement for the student to be able to produce their music freely.  Adding a little context about this would help.

**Genre**

Some genres of music *do* change time signature from time to time, some almost never change, and some change very frequently.  If she is writing music in a mainstream dance genre, for example, changing time signatures frequently would not probably work well.  We expect dance music of a specific kind to follow a time signature convention and stick with it.  If she is composing a piece for a group of young musicians or amateurs to play, they may be confused by the time signatures.  But if she is creating it for electronic playback, or a professional-level ensemble, changing time signatures as often as the composer desires is perfectly reasonable.  A little context in this realm would help, too.

Comment: You've missed the point. A time signature change can be incorrect. For example notate 'Happy Birthday' but change to 5/4 in the second measure. You'd almost certainly agree that's wrong. It makes no musical sense.

Comment: I guess we need a little more info from the OP then.  I read it as wondering whether a time signature change at all/in general is acceptable.   Of course there are specific instances like you mention where the choice of time signature is simply wrong.

Comment: @PiedPiper if you are writing down existing music without a time signature change then writing one is obviously incorrect. The question is whether it's not allowed to write *new* music with a time signature change.

Comment: @PiedPiper - often in Happy Birthday, bar 6 changes time signature drastically!

Comment: @user253751 My example was badly formulated. I should have written "if you are composing a simple melody like 'Happy Birthday'..."

Comment: @Tim That's a place where there probably **should** be a time signature change (4/4 or even 5/4). Seems I picked the wrong example.

Comment: @user253751 Happy Birthday is just an example, chosen because it is a well known melody.  It's also possible to compose a new piece that is entirely in one time signature only and write it down with an incorrect time signature change (or, conversely, to compose a new piece that has a time signature change but write it down incorrectly all in one time signature).  It's just too difficult in the space of a stack exchange comment to compose a novel example to illustrate this.

Comment: "often in Happy Birthday, bar 6 changes time signature drastically"  Only if you choose to interpret a fermata that way!  And I'd rate doing so as an error.

Comment: @Laurence I disagree that it's a fermata at all. Have you ever seen a group of birthday singers hold that note until cued to continue? No, every single person knows to add exactly one extra beat.

Comment: Check this version out, and weep! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_z-1fTlSDF0

Comment: Oh dear, @Laurence, that is dreadful!  I don't even know where to start...

Answer (score 2):

The question is worded a bit strangely, it really depends on what exactly the question is asking. I think the better way to ask the question is "When is the usage of a time signature change inappropriate", since it's easier to explain *when* a time signature change is non-standard, rather than "are time-signature changes appropriate?"

As some users in the comments mentioned, it would be inappropriate to use a time signature change on an *existing* piece of music in which the time signature is already well-known or commonplace, say, "Twinkle Twinkle Little Star". The piece is in 4/4 throughout, and to change the time signature would be *arguably* wrong (or at least very confusing to read). After all, time signatures are supposed to provide clarity in beat and/or divisions of beat(s), and if it's providing more confusion than clarity, it's (probably) wrong.

However, there are also instances in which time signature changes maybe inappropriate to use even in a compositional setting. First, such changes may be unsuitable or inapplicable to the style. For example, most American marches are written in some divisions of two (2/4, 2/2, or 6/8), since its music was constructed for, well, marching. A change in the time signature (even into 4/4!) would be confusing for those performing the piece.

Of course, it could be feasible for a composer seeking some spice in their writing to perhaps switch from cut-time into 6/8 (or vice versa), but this sort of practice is generally uncommon within American marches, which (at least ones composed by Sousa and his contemporaries) generally also followed a fairly strict form (if you're curious, you can read about that [here!](https://www.nhme.org/_media/march-form2.pdf))

---

A time signature changes can also be wrong or unnecessary from a pure notation point of view. For example, if I wrote something like this:

[image]

This is wrong (sort of). Isolated, this is just a 9/8 figure, and unless there's some good contextual reason for this being here, most people would also argue that this should just be written as 9/8. However, things get a little bit more interesting if I were to write it as such:

[image]

Now there's actually a reason for the time signature change. A 9/8 pattern suggests a triple compound pattern (1-2-3, 1-2-3, 1-2-3), but what I've written below suggests a (1-2-3, 1-2/ 1-2, 1-2) pattern, though it could also easily be written like this:

[image]

or even just this:

[image]

Many of these changes would largely depend on the context of the piece, and different ones would make more sense. For example, if my piece was generally in 9/8 and I wanted to just mess with the meter a bit, I would probably write it like this:

[image]

It wouldn't make sense for me to change the time signature (unless there was some very good reasoning otherwise) since it just clutters the page. However, if I were to compose something more metrically complex like...

[image]

... the 5/8+2/4 pattern makes more sense here.[Link here if you're curious on how it sounds](https://musescore.com/user/20640026/scores/10366177).

(Sorry if the melody sounds rushed, it's because I wrote it in like 15 minutes just for this example).

So yeah, TL;DR, context matters. Opt for clarity - if changing the time signature makes your piece make more sense, then it should be used. Otherwise, just stick with the time signature you have, and be aware of the style you're writing for, to be wary if it is appropriate or inappropriate to incorporate it.

Comment: If anyone's curious on how the 9/8 melody sounds, I can upload that too, though that one's fairly simple and short enough that you could just play it on piano.

Answer (score 1):

Time signature changes are allowed, and commonplace, particularly in modern styles.

The time signature changes your daughter has written  may be inappropriate, an inefficient way of notating her musical intention.

If you show us a page of her score, we can usefully discuss whether this is the case!